# Using Launchbar to make Popclip appear

Tags: macos, applescript, automation, launchbar, copy-paste

**PopClip** is a Mac app that adds the iOS functionality of a bunch of options showing up above selected text. PopClip automatically appears every time I select text, and that's annoying, so I want to trigger it from the keyboard instead. I'm trying to set up **Launchbar** to launch an Applescript to cause PopClip to appear next to selected text.

The Applescript I'm using is `tell application "PopClip" to appear`. However, when I press ↩ with the text selected in Mail and "Show Pop Clip.scpt" selected in Launchbar, nothing happens. And when I press ⇥ as Obdev (the Launchbar developer) [recommends here](http://www.obdev.at/resources/launchbar/help/RunningAppleScripts.html), I don't see an option to "Run" as they suggest.

How can I use Launchbar to make Popclip appear?

Answer (score 1):

With Launchbar you can run scripts in the background by pressing Option+Return, rather than just Return. This works for me, whereas Return by itself did not.